# ¿Como darle formato a una columna cuando creo un excel con PHP?

Tags: php, excel, formato

La cuestión es esa, tengo una table en html y dentro del php un header.

```
$filename = uniqid() . '.xls';
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=iso-8859-15');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
```

y mi tabla es así:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Total 1</th>
    <th>Total 2</th>
    <th>Total 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="mso-number-format:#,##0.00;">193600.00</td>
    <td style="mso-number-format:'#,##0.00';">193600.00</td>
    <td>'193600.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Como se puede apreciar, tengo el `style="mso-number-format:#,##0.00;"` que es lo que conseguí por Internet. Eso debería formatear el número a `193,600.00` pero no lo hace. Las otras formas son alternativas que vi pero tampoco funciona.

Todos me dejan el número como si fuese texto

Quisiera que se viera como moneda, para poder hacer sumas. Gracias!

Comment: Te lo reconoce como texto porque estás poniendo `193600.00`, que para Excel en principio es un valor de texto (aunque tú luego quieres aplicarle otro formato).Si cambias el punto por una coma y pones `193600.00` debería cogértelo.

Otra cosa es lo del aplicar el cambio de formato, porque posiblemente ahí tengas que jugar con `mso-displayed-decimal-separator` y `mso-displayed-thousand-separator`, pero no tengo ni idea de usarlos. Sé que en Excel si quiero cambiar el separador decimal, hay que hacerlo desde la configuración del programa, ya que por defecto coge la regional (en mi caso España)

Comment: Finalmente no logré mucho con esto, tuve que entregarlo de forma sencilla transformando con `echo (float) $numero;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo  lo realizo de la siguiente manera

```
<td class="moneda"> <?php echo formatDollars(round($Sueldo, 2)); ?></td> <!-- SALARIO DIARIO
```

esta es mi función

```
function formatDollars($dollars)
{
    $formatted = "$" . number_format(sprintf('%0.2f', preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $dollars)), 2);
    return $dollars < 0 ? "-{$formatted}" : "{$formatted}";
}
```

espero te funcione

Comment: Gracias, si funcionó